# "Rendering" Objects in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

New to AngularJS here (have used BackboneJS before), and am trying to learn AngularJS. I'm attempting to basically render a bunch of objects with their own `div` "views." In my controller, I have an array of objects (all objects with same properties) that I would pretty much like to render as sticky-notes. My thought process was to somehow grab the data from each object in the array, and render each as `div`'s (which I could style to look like a sticky-note).

The code I have thus far:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http, Note) {
  $scope.notesArray= [];
  $http.get('notes_data.json').success(function(data) { // basically grab all the data from a JSON file
    data.data.forEach(function(obj) {
        $scope.notesArray.push(obj);
    });
  })
}]);
```

My **index.html** looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp">
            <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
                Some stuff here
            </div>
        </div>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, it'd be great if someone could comment on how I can represent these objects more effectively (using a factory, service, etc). Thanks!

Comment: have you looked at `ng-repeat` yet?

Comment: do seperate the ajax into service and call that service..get that data from there and then show it on UI using `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this, with `ng-repeat` :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp">
            <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
                <div class="note" ng-repeat="note in notesArray">
                    <div class="wrapper" ng-class="note.done ? 'done' : 'undone'">
                        <p class="title">{{note.title}}</p>
                        <span class="done">{{note.done}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome! It seems that this way would render the notes all the same way. What if you wanted to include logic to render some notes differently from others?

Comment: It depends on which criteria you want to render them differently. If it is related to a value of an attribute, you can use `ng-if` or `ng-class`, if you want to display differently even/odd notes, you can read more about `ng-repeat` here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat.
I edited my question to show you how to set a class in relation to the `done` status.